# assertEquals issue when during type comparison

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, junit

all.

I try to check a class type with the some actual object's class type:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test; // ???
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void addition_isCorrect() {

        BhriguActivity object = new BhriguActivity();

        assertEquals(object.getClass(), BhriguActivity.class);

    }
}
```

It's funny but the result of it:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :class info.bhrigu.javaasanatimer.ExampleUnitTest$1
Actual   :info.bhrigu.javaasanatimer.ExampleUnitTest$1@3c756e4d
```

Why the test try to compare with "info.bhrigu.javaasanatimer.ExampleUnitTest" instead of BhriguActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong Test annotation

use

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

instead of

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```